# MongoDB não reconhecendo comando quando alguém escreve algo na frente

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, chatbot

Eu tenho um bot e salvo seus comandos no banco de dados MongoDB, mas quando escrevo, por exemplo, "!comando e outras coisas em uma linha" ele não responde, como poderia ignorar essas outras palavras?

Meu código é:

```
client.on('chat',(channel, user, message, self) => {
    if(message.substr(0,1)==='!' && !message.startsWith('!add') && !message.startsWith('!deletecommand') && !message.startsWith('!comandos')) {
        const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
        const url = "my-url";
        MongoClient.connect(url,(err,dbclient) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('DB foi conectado com sucesso');
                const database = dbclient.db('twitchbot');
                const collection = database.collection("commands");
                collection.findOne({command:message}).then(result => {
                    if(result) {
                        client.say(ch, result.message );
                    }
                });
            }
            dbclient.close();
        });
    } else if (message.startsWith('!add') && (user['user-type']==='mod' || user['display-name'].toLowerCase()==='helderjunior')) {
        const newcommand = '!'+message.split(" ")[1].replace(/[^\w\s]/gi,'')
        const newmessage = message.split(" ").slice(2).join(" ");
        const newitem = {command: newcommand, message: newmessage};
        const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
        const url = "my-url";
        MongoClient.connect(url,(err,dbclient) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("DB foi conectado com sucesso");
                const database = dbclient.db('twitchbot');
                const collection = database.collection('commands');
                collection.insertOne(newitem).then(result => {
                    client.say(ch,'O comando foi criado com susseso: '+newcommand);
                    console.log(result);
                }).catch(err => {
                    client.say(ch,'Não consegui criar o comando, helderjunior Panela');
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
            dbclient.close();
```

[image: o que acontece]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de resolver seria fazendo o [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) da mensagem antes de fazer a consulta no mongodb.

> O método split() divide uma String em uma lista de
> substrings, coloca essas substrings em um array e retorna o array. A
> divisão é feita procurando um padrão, onde o padrão é fornecido como o
> primeiro parâmetro na chamada do método.

O padrão que devemos utilizar é o caractere `espaço em branco` (U+0020)

Repare a utilização da função `split` na variável `message`, utilizando como separador o `espaço em branco`.

Utilizando o seu código seria algo assim:

```
if(message.substr(0,1)==='!' && !message.startsWith('!add') && !message.startsWith('!deletecommand') && !message.startsWith('!comandos')) {
        const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
        const url = "my-url";
        MongoClient.connect(url,(err,dbclient) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('DB foi conectado com sucesso');
                const database = dbclient.db('twitchbot');
                const arrcmd = message.split(' ')
                if (arrcmd.length > 0) {
                    const collection = database.collection("commands");
                    collection.findOne({command:arrcmd[0]}).then(result => {
                        if(result) {
                            client.say(ch, result.message );
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            dbclient.close();
        });
    }
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado de verdade!